# Create an EventBridge rule that targets a lambda function defined in a separate stack using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have 3 separate stacks (all in the same account and region)

1. The he AuthStack authenticates and sends a new user event object to the EventsBusStack via a lambda postConfirmation trigger lambda function.
2. The EventBusStack receives the newUser object via the postConfirmation lambda.
3. However, using the CDK I can't seem to figure out a way to target the lambda function located in the third stack, the RewardsStack. The CDK seems to not provide a way to target the lambda function via its arn.

How to create a rule that targets a lambda function located in a different stack using the CDK?

Comment: did u find a solution for the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `Function.fromFunctionArn` to use the ARN.